# How to rewrite URL in an ASP.net site

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite URL in an asp.net site

What i need is i don't want the user to see in which language the site was created

i.e it should not have `www.examplesite.com/index.aspx` as address

instead i want it as `www.examplesite.com/index`

I don't want the user to see the extension of files

If this question is not related to Stackoverflow please redirect this question to the respective site of Stack Exchange.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That is called URL rewriting, not deploying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS URL Rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089183/iis-url-rewrite)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this at a simple level in the Global.asax file like this:

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires at the beginning of each request

    Dim path As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path

    If path.ToLower.EndsWith(".aspx") Then
        path = path.Substring(0, path.Length - 5)
        Response.Redirect(path, True)
    Else
        path += ".aspx"
        Context.RewritePath(path)
    End If

End Sub
```

If you have other files that are requested such as .png files, you may need some additional logic to filter these out.

Answer (score 2):

In web.config file, add below code.

```
<rewrite>
       <rules>
            <clear />

                <rule name="exampleredirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^index.aspx" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/index" />
                </rule>
        </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Please refer the below link.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1910607.aspx?web+config+rewrite+rule

Comment: I'm getting an error Unrecognized configuration section `rewrite`

Comment: I have added the code under `System.WebServer` now i'm not getting error but still i'm able to see the extension. I'm checking it in LocalHost

Comment: You need to install the [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module) on you server for this to work

Comment: Thank you for your response..!! The solution provided by **[Matt Wilko](http://stackoverflow.com/users/500974/matt-wilko)** is the simplest and easy one..!! So i have marked his as answer and i have upvoted your's

Answer (score 2):

The issue related with your question is the `URL Rewriting` in ASP.Net. For URL rewriting there are various approaches: writing rewrite module in `IIS` or using `ASP.NET Web.config` file.

For using `web.config` file, you've to first of all add rewrite configuration section and the define the rewrite rule as per your requirement within the `<rewrite > </rewrite>` tags.

For more details: follow this [Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response..!! The solution provided by **[Matt Wilko](http://stackoverflow.com/users/500974/matt-wilko)** is the simplest and easy one..!! So i have marked his as answer and i have upvoted your's

Answer (score 0):

There is a nuget package for this I think, its called [Friendly Urls](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your response..!! The solution provided by [Matt Wilko](http://stackoverflow.com/users/500974/matt-wilko) is the simplest and easy one..!! Thank you making me know about the Fiendly URL's ..! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config you'd have to add a section called `<rewrite> </rewrite>`, then you would add rules/rule names as I've done below:

```
            <rewrite><rules><clear />
               <rule name="redirectrule" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="^index.aspx" />
               <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false" />
               <action type="Redirect" url="/index" />
            </rule></rules></rewrite>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response..!! The solution provided by [Matt Wilko](http://stackoverflow.com/users/500974/matt-wilko) is the simplest and easy one..!!