# Adding Page Routing To Legacy C#/ASPX Web Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, webforms

I am working on legacy C# & ASP.NET Webforms project where I would like to add routing in order to make the URLs more "friendly" to the user, while a longer-term replacement application is being built, which will utilize the same URLs through ASP.NET MVC.

Not being intimately familiar with the patterns necessary to properly implement .NET page routing, I'm wondering where I am going wrong with the code. What I have currently in place is that most of the `.ASPX` pages are in a `Pages` folder within the solution, and a peer-level `Account` folder, which has pages strictly related to user account management (`Login.aspx`, `ForgotPassword.aspx` etc.). The project owner wants the `Pages` folder omitted from any URL, but wants `account` included in the URL when navigating to account-related actions.

So this is what I am trying to accomplish through routing (trailing slash optional):

```
myurl.com/account/{login} -->  ~/account/{login}.aspx
myurl.com/{foo}           -->  ~/pages/{foo}.aspx
myurl.com/                -->  ~/pages/default.aspx
Anything else             -->  ~/pages/error404.aspx
```

*(I would have posted the actual code I was trying to run, but the SO "Ask A Public Question" page kept erroring out with the "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" message)*

What I am also trying to do is limit URLs to the actual pages I have available, and to strip off any extraneous text off the end of the URL.

Any help (or at least a push in the right direction) would be helpful and GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The term you're looking for is "URL Rewriting" (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756107/how-to-rewrite-url-in-an-asp-net-site)

Comment: Microsoft published an add-on for webforms called [FriendlyUrl](https://www.codeguru.com/dotnet/using-friendly-urls-in-asp-net-web-forms/) that accomplishes this - providing routing and MVC-like URL's, mapped to individual ASPX pages

Comment: @JeremyLakeman no, I do not want rewriting. I believe I can get the necessary results in just a handful of routes. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @marc_s I'm not sure this is going to get me to where I need to go. I need something a bit more generic, to handle pages in the "pages" folder without needing that segment in the URL, but then needing to include account for pages in the "account" folder.